# Dúvida sobre qual Herança usar no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-service, xamarin, herança

Apenas tive a oportunidade de usar o EF basicamente 1x. Portanto, estou com muitas dúvidas, mesmmo consultando bastante o google. 
Eu tenho uma aplicação client que vai pegar diversos dados do Facebook do usuário logado...

Jogando no Json2Charp tenho as seguintes classes:

```
    public class UserData
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string idface { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public Hometown hometown { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Events events { get; set; }
        public Likes likes { get; set; }
        public Age_Range age_range { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public Picture picture { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hometown
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Events
    {
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paging
    {
        public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cursors
    {
        public string before { get; set; }
        public string after { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime start_time { get; set; }
        public Place place { get; set; }
        public int attending_count { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string rsvp_status { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_time { get; set; }
    }

    public class Place
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public LocationEvent location { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocationEvent
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
    }

    public class Likes
    {
        public Datum1[] data { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum1
    {
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int fan_count { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public LocationEvent location { get; set; }
        public string[] emails { get; set; }
    }


    public class Age_Range
    {
        public int min { get; set; }
    }

    public class Picture
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public bool is_silhouette { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

Ao criar um webapi pra conectar com meu Azure SQL, pensei em usar o EF code first pra facilitar minha vida. Li então sobre Heranças e achei o mais adequado ao meu uso. Porém, acredito que minha classe teria que mudar para por exemplo:

```
    public class UserData
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string idface { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

    }

    public class Hometown : UserData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location : UserData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    E assim por diante....
```

Estou correto ? Esse seria o mais correto ou consigo com minha classe informada primeiro? 
Se sim, qual seria a mais correta a implementar ? TPT ?

Li tambem sobre Complex Types.

Mas a dúvida restou...sobre o que usar.

Answer (score 1):

É mais interessante utilizar a herança sim já que o principio da reusabilidade é um dos pilares da orientação a objeto. Vou fazer um comentário superficial da sua proposta utilizando herança e você faça as outras modificações necessárias, como realocar as propriedades que UserData possuía antes de você fazer a herança.

Levando em conta o fato que o Entity Framework compreende a herança, você colocar um id como `int` e outro como `string` é uma redundância mesmo que tenham tipo diferentes. Normalmente a propriedade Id é o nome da propriedade que representa a chave primária, então eu recomendo manter apenas uma na superclasse.

Esse ponto eu vou discutir e você toma a decisão de especialista. Teoricamente a propriedade Nome seria utilizada em ambas entidades, porém se o objetivo de UserData é ser a superclasse de todas entidades do sistema (não apenas essas duas), não é interessante que ele possua essa propriedade já que nem todas entidades possuem Nome. Todavia, se o objetivo de UserData é ser a superclasse de apenas essas duas entidades, é interessante que a super classe possua essa propriedade.

**Mais sobre:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: No meu caso UserData são os dados principais do usuario...ele sempre terá nome...
Obrigado pela dica... Devo ler sobre Tipos Complexos e fazer uso então ne?

Comment: Quando você diz tipos complexos se refere a isso: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/complex-type ?

Comment: https://olavooneto.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/tipos-complexos-com-code-first/

Comment: Compreendi, é sempre interessante ler sobre assuntos do gênero, mas não recomendo que você aplique o conceito de tipos complexos no seu exemplo. A primeira vista do jeito que você mapeou não seria interessante ter uma tabela única para as três entidades e sim duas separadas: HomeTown e Location, já que estaríamos quebrando a terceira forma de normalização de banco de dados utilizando um tipo complexo no exemplo..

Comment: Agora notei, você esta confundindo o exemplo dele com herança, perceba que no exemplo de tipo complexo ele não usa herança e tudo vira uma entidade só, no caso da herança é um pouco diferente.

Comment: vira uma entidade só, mas as classes são criadas do mesmo jeito que no model do client... isso que me confunde em qual adotar...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68384/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-mc-fer).